# Why does my if/else condition with hasClass only fire first condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The else condition of my if/else is not firing. The condition is for the li.catparent, so that if it is clicked, I can have certain code fired. If one of the other items without 'li.catparent' is clicked, then different code will be fired. Perhaps someone could tell me what I'm missing? My if/else statement is very simple, and I'm not sure why it isn't firing. I definitely missing something.

HTML:

```
    <ul class="portal-filter categorylist" id="filter">
        <li class="all"><a class="selected" href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
        <li class="category"><a href="#" data-filter=".category1">Category 1</a></li>
        <li class="category"><a href="#" data-filter=".category2">Category 2</a></li>
        <li class="catparent">
            <span class="catparenttxt">
                Category Parent

                <span class="subnavarrow"></span>
            </span>

            <ul class="subcatlist">
                <li class="category"><a href="#" data-filter=".subcategory1">Subcategory 1</a></li>
                <li class="category"><a href="#" data-filter=".subcategory1">Subcategory 2</a></li>
                <li class="category"><a href="#" data-filter=".subcategory1">Subcategory 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="category"><a href="#" data-filter=".category1, .category2">Category 1 and 2</a></li>
    </ul>
```

jQuery

```
    $('ul.categorylist > li').on('click', function(){

        if($(this).hasClass('catparent')){
            console.log('category parent clicked');
        }

        else{
            console.log('category without parent clicked');
        }

    });
```

or

```
    $('ul.categorylist > li').on('click', function(){

        if($(this).hasClass('catparent')){
            console.log('category parent clicked');
        }

        else if(!$(this).hasClass('catparent')){
            console.log('category without parent clicked');
        }

    });
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfvq09as/) that seems to be working with the simple code.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ub3ubr5u/) with my entire project code included that shows it isn't working.

Comment: simplest way: Use only else without if: `else{ console.log(...) }`

Comment: @MartinErnst: He already is. @ ScriptsConnect: Your code works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/rLdkcvLd/

Comment: other way put condition into parenthesis and then negate the whole: `else if (!($(this).hasClass('catparent')))`

Comment: Seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/j69sqhus/

Comment: @MartinErnst: That's no different.

Comment: Yep, what the others said - your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/0rbaandu/

Comment: Thanks for your reply squint - I just checked your fiddle and it does work. It must be an issue with my project setup then. This is very odd. I have all JS being loaded in the footer. Could this perhaps play a role in this not working?

Comment: No, that won't make a difference. Do you have the HTML in your question nested inside other `li` elements that may have the `catparent` class? If so, you're binding to those as well and the event bubbles up and invokes those handlers.

Comment: If you can post your full html code, we can help.

Comment: I just moved all my JS to the head, and it still doesn't work in my project. I'm using jQuery 1.10.2 locally, and after switching to 1.10.1 in jsfiddle, the fiddles still worked. So I'll have to investigate why there's a problem in my solution. There are no JS errors appearing. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Apul Gupta, I will shortly. There are a lot of files associated with this project, so I'll have to upload to a server and paste a link here.

Comment: @squint, I don't. I'm using that class only one time in my markup, exactly as was pasted above. Only 1 instance in the project for now.

Comment: Not sure then. Need a full working example of the issue.

Comment: @ScriptsConnect, just post your generated html. It will help us to figure out.

Comment: @ScriptsConnect posting an external link to the question is frowned upon here at SO. Post the question and code here so that the external link doesn't become stale or becomes changed to working.

Comment: I managed to get a fiddle with all dependencies put in:

http://jsfiddle.net/ub3ubr5u/

In that JS Fiddle you'll see that only the 'if' statement is being fired, and the else is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue appears to be related to the media boxes plugin that you have used. If you take the `$('#grid').mediaBoxes({ ... });` part out of the broken JSFiddle you have provided, it works perfectly as expected. You can see this fix in the updated JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ub3ubr5u/1/).

To work around this issue, you need to handle the clicks on the `a` tags inside the list items as well:

```
$('ul.categorylist > li, ul.categorylist > li a').on('click', function() {
    ....
});
```

Comment: How come it works in my original JS Fiddle without your modification, in which it is much lighter (only using the navigation), but still uses the same structure?

Comment: @ScriptsConnect - it appears to be related to the media boxes plugin. If you take the `$('#grid').mediaBoxes({ ... });` part out of your broken JSFiddle, it works with just the `li` selector. See this updated JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ub3ubr5u/1/

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the click-event is actually only triggered for the li.catparent; this is due to the anchor-elements inside the other lis, that consume the mouse click.

You can add a handler to those, too, to receive the event:

```
$('ul.categorylist li a').on('click', function(e) {
 alert('a inside li clicked');
}
```